# Login ID and password are reset when using browser .click() event so it can't do automatic login in Python

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, click, sendkeys

I can see the text is sent to each input box. But when browser.find_element_by_class_name('btn_login').click() runs, the text is deleted. And it refreshes the page. Why? Does it detect my code as a bot? I tried some bypass code but still a problem.

```
id = browser.find_element_by_id('login_id')
id.send_keys(user_id)  # Enter your ID
# clipboard_input('//*[@id="login_id"]', user_id)
time.sleep(3)
pw = browser.find_element_by_id('login_pw')
pw.send_keys(user_pw)  # Enter your password
# clipboard_input('//*[@id="login_pw"]', user_pw)
time.sleep(3)
browser.find_element_by_class_name('btn_login').click()
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Comment: Which site is it?

Comment: just college portal site